# clang in Xcode 7.2 generates vxorps

Tags: clang, avx, xcode7.2

I encountered an issue where compiling cryptopp with clang from Xcode 7.2 generates a vxorps instruction in ByteQueue::ByteQueue(unsigned long). Since our product can be run on old CPUs where this instruction triggers illegal instruction I need to tackle this somehow. Can I turn off AVX somehow? Or is the only workaround upgrading Xcode?

Comment: Xcode is based on clang.  In regular clang, the baseline is x86-64, and doesn't include AVX.  Don't use `-mavx` or `-march=haswell` (or sandybridge) for code that targets CPUs without AVX.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the response, I tracked this down to a change in crypto++ which now was using -march=native and thus causing the build machine to pick up the capabilities from the build machine. But I still added -mno-avx just to be safe.